# load data from csv file with foreign key liquibase

Tags: liquibase

I am trying to populate 2 tables through csv files in liquibase.
I have one table called tenant and one another named tenant_configuration and have foreign key to tenant. First part is load tenant data:

```
<changeSet id="1" context="test">
    <comment>Insert data for tenant table</comment>
    <loadUpdateData
            primaryKey="id"
            file="tenant.csv"
            tableName="tenant"/>
</changeSet>
```

Then i would like to use another csv file to populate tenant config but retrieve  tenant_id from first change.

```
   <changeSet id="2" context="test">
    <comment>Insert data for tenant_db_configuration table</comment>
    <loadData tableName="tenant_db_configuration"
              file="tenant_db_configuration.csv"
              separator="," >
        <column name="tenant_id" type="NUMERIC" defaultValueComputed="(SELECT ID FROM tenant WHERE tenant_id = tenant_1)"/>
        <column header="username" name="username" type="STRING"/>
        <column header="password" name="password" type="STRING"/>
    </loadData>
</changeSet>
```

Tried this but liquibase ignore the tenant_id part and shows:

```
[Failed SQL: INSERT INTO [dbo].[tenant_db_configuration] ([username], [password]) VALUES...
```

how i can retrieve that foreign key and merge with existing csv file to load data?

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know you will need to make the relation manually in the secomnd CSV file, tenant_db_configuration.csv. I mean, each row in there will need to be pointing to an existent id in the tenat Table.

If the order doesnt matters bc you trust in your csv data, You could disable the foreign key checks with a changeSet before starting to import the data.

I dunno wich DBMS are you using but with MYSQL is

```
<changeSet author="liquibase-docs" id="sql-example">
    <sql dbms="mysql">
        SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```

and then you can enable it after on a separate changeSet.

It's been 3 months since the question, so Hope it helps. If you solved it already, what was the solution?